# Android getLocationOnScreen returns incorrect point after the view rotation

Tags: android, rotation, point, ontouchlistener

I'm using `getLocationOnScreen()` from Android SDK for getting the location point.
when I rotate the `View` using gestures I get the wrong point.
Has anyone already encountered such a problem?